# Ormlite very slow

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have a simple table with only 6 quite simple fields, and only 2 rows in the table.  When running the query

SELECT *
FROM PersonsPreferences

from MS SQL Server Management Studio, "Client Statistics" reports running times around 0-1 millisconds.  As expected.

However, when I use Ormlite, I get vastly larger running times - around 30 milliseconds.  My C# Ormlite code is as follows:

```
Stopwatch lSW = new Stopwatch();
lSW.Start();
PersonPreference lPMPExisting = db.Select<PersonPreference>().FirstOrDefault();
var e = lSW.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Now, in the above code, "e" gets value around 30, which is far more than it should be.  'PersonPreference' is a very simple class for accessing the corresponding DB table.  I use Ormlite 5.0, newest version is 5.5, but my DB access is so basic that 5.0 should be more than good enough?   Any suggestions?

Best,
Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things. First the stopwatch:

- use `Stop()` before retrieving elapsed time
- check the `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution` to make sure your tests are accurate
- run multiple tests, eliminate warm ups, calculate average timing

For the ORM itself, your Management Studio usually connects to the server instance and retains a session. As such the client statistics don’t contain connecting to the server, authentication and handshake. The code you posted hides if you open a connection to the db before initializing the stopwatch.
In your example you ‘select’ / retrieve multiple `PersonPreference` s and apply LINQ FirstOrDefault afterwards on the collection, which has a negative impact on your performance.
When you say that the execution time

> is far more than it should be.

what range did you expect and did you compare the query to EF, dapper, Nhibernate or anything else?

Any ORM no matter if heavy or micro, handles multiple responsibilities and will perform poorer than a direct sql query using a dbms.

Comment: Use Stop() before getting elapsed time made no noticeable difference.  The StopWatch is confirmed to be 'IsHighResolution'.  FYI:  Doing the call a 1000 times in a loop does not change the average time. Sometimes the first run is around 45 ms.  
Surrounding code:

```
using (var db = Startup.DbFactory().OpenDbConnection())
{
     db.Open();
     // <above code>
     db.Close();
}
```
So, opening the DB factory/connection is not part of measured time.

Removing 'FirstOrDefault()' makes no time difference.

Expected result is around 1 ms, this DB read is as simple as it get.

Comment: The advises for the stopwatch were general and of course micro optimizations. Now you have a benchmark for OrmLite and you can compare it to the other mentioned ORMs. When you choose one, also consider feature fullness, caching levels, readability, documentation and so on. There is not the best or fastest tool for object relationship mapping, you can find the one that fits you or your team best and to solve specific problems.

Comment: SOLVED (IN A BAD WAY...).   I just upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 (Professional) to Visual Studio 2019 (Enterprise).  In 2017 average time <1 ms on the call.......

Yes, this sounds a bit crazy, but I was able to open the exact same project in 2017 that I had run in 2019, so all code should be equal when I went from 2019 back to 2017.  So, somehow Visual Studio 2019 (Enterprise) puts a huge overhead on the call.

Comment: To anyone interested:  I have tracked down the issue to Tools | Options | Debugging | General | Enable Diagnostics Tools while debugging:  Turn OFF this switch and code executes quick, and DB read takes much less than 1 ms in average when using StopWatch to measure elapsed time.

Comment: More info for anyone encountering this:

Seems as if StopWatch Start with Elapsed measure not is working properly when running inside VisualStudio.

I consistently measure times around 8-15 ms inside VisualStudio, but if running outside of VisualStudio and instead reporting the measured times to e.g. file, then the measured times get low - around 0 to 1 ms - as expected.

If it is StopWatch itself that works poorly inside VisualStudio, or it the measured DB call (e.g. overhead around the call) that is slower when inside VisualStudio, I can not say.